# Postgres | Convert Rows of Arrays to Rows of Integers

Tags: json, postgresql, insert

I've hit a roadblock that I can't seem to get past as I'm not able to visualize the data. I'm fairly new to Postgres (more experienced with Snowflake, but no longer have access), but due to the complexity and inserts I'm not able to visualize the data.

Looking at other posts, the closest I was able to get is the following (which only presents a blank response which I believe has something to do with the TWO subquery, but am otherwise lost):

Table ALPHA (Empty table)

```
CREATE TABLE ALPHA (
  X_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  X_JSON JSON
);
```

Table CHARLIE (Filled table)

```
CREATE TABLE CHARLIE (
  Y_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO CHARLIE (Y_ID, NAME)
VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'D'),(5,'E'),(6,'F'),(7,'G'),(8,'H'),(9,'I'),(10,'J'),(11,'K'),(12,'L');
```

Table BRAVO (Empty intermediary table)

```
CREATE TABLE BRAVO (
  X_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES ALPHA (X_ID),
  Y_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES CHARLIE (Y_ID)
);
```

Query:

```
WITH ONE AS (
  INSERT INTO ALPHA (X_ID, X_JSON)
  VALUES (1, '{"a": [4,5,6]}'),
         (2, '{"a": [7,8,9]}'),
         (3, '{"a": [10,11,12]}')
  RETURNING X_ID, JSON_EXTRACT_PATH(X_JSON, 'a') AS Y_ID
), TWO AS (
  SELECT ALPHA.X_ID,
         (SELECT * FROM JSON_TO_RECORDSET(ONE.Y_ID -> 'rows') AS list(columns int)) AS Y_ID_A
  FROM ALPHA
    JOIN ONE ON ALPHA.X_ID = ONE.X_ID
)
INSERT INTO BRAVO (X_ID, Y_ID)
SELECT X_ID,
       Y_ID_A
FROM TWO
RETURNING *
```

What I need the output to look like so I can insert it into table BRAVO:

| X_ID | Y_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 3 | 12 |

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aq6m_ddh)

Comment: Why do you store json content as text? PostgreSQL has json and jsonb data types

Comment: @FrankHeikens I misposted. The first insert is storing the JSON as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`json_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) to expands a JSON array to a set of rows :

```
WITH ONE AS (
  INSERT INTO ALPHA (X_ID, X_JSON)
  VALUES (1, '{"a": [4,5,6]}'),
         (2, '{"a": [7,8,9]}'),
         (3, '{"a": [10,11,12]}')
  RETURNING X_ID, X_JSON->'a' AS Y_ID_A
),
TWO AS (
  SELECT o.X_ID, v.value::text::int AS Y_ID
  FROM ONE o
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements (o.Y_ID_A) v
)
INSERT INTO BRAVO (X_ID, Y_ID)
SELECT X_ID,
       Y_ID
FROM TWO
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q2Oh-eL7)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
I made an error when specifying the table being inserted into (there is no TABLE_A). I've corrected this.

Looking over your DBFiddle, you've specified the BRAVO.Y_ID to be JSON, where its an INT.

Comment: Can you check my recent edit

Comment: That works, thank you kindly!

I'd prefer a cleaner type conversion, but I can sort that out.

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :)